# DropDownListFor returns null to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I know that there are another similar questions, but i can't find working solution anywhere.

The point is that i want from user to select date in dropDownList, get that date as an argument for action method and depending on selected date show results from database. But all the time, after choosing any item in dropDownList it returns null to controller.

Here is my controller's methods:

```
    public ActionResult Index(DateViewModel dateViewModel)
    {
        dateViewModel.Dates = GetDates();

        return View(dateViewModel);
    }

    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDates()
    {
        var dbContext = new DbContext();

        var dates = dbContext .TestResults
            .Where(result => result.CompletedOn != null)
            .OrderBy(result => result.CompletedOn)
            .Select(result => result.CompletedOn).ToList();

        var sortedDates = dates
            .GroupBy(date => date.Month)
            .Select(date => date.First())
            .Select(date => new SelectListItem { Text = date.ToString("MMMM yy"), Value = date.Month.ToString() + " " + date.Year.ToString()})
            .ToList();

         return new SelectList(sortedDates, "Value", "Text");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowDepartmentArchive(string date)
    {
        //some logic with date here
        return PartialView(depResults);
    }
```

I have a ViewModel for dropDownList:

```
public class DateViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Выбранная дата")]
    public string SelectedDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Выберите дату: ")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Dates { get; set; }
}
```

And, finally in my view:

```
   @model QA.Web.App.Models.DateViewModel
       @using (Html.BeginForm("ShowDepartmentArchive", "Archive"))
       {
           @Html.Hidden("SelectedDate", Model.SelectedDate)
           @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDate, Model.Dates, "Выберите 
   дату", new {onchange = "this.form.submit();"})}
```

Comment: You have a hidden input for `SelectedDate` and its the value of that input that will be bound (the value of the `<select>` will be ignored - you need to delete that input. In addition, your query already generates a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` so it pointless extra overhead to use `new SelectList(..)` to create another identical one - just use `return sortedDates;`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thank you for answer. I've changed my code as you told, but still have null as the returned value. I tried to debug it with break point, and i can see value that i need - [imgur](https://imgur.com/a/s8ebAuN)

Comment: Your POST method needs to be `public ActionResult ShowDepartmentArchive(DateViewModel model)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you very much, now it works!